# Rails Form Submissions All Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, devise

Every single form in my **Rails 4** application suddenly fail.

I have a relatively big app with plenty of nested resources and routing, and using user auth with *Devise*. There is no error message, no validation errors, or application errors. It just refreshes the page and leaves all of the form fields blank.

And has a `utf8=✓&authenticity_token=(plus the token)` appended to the **URL**. I can't place where my error was and why this happened. I think it may have something to do with Devise, but I've reinstalled Devise successfully and put my routes back to the way they were.

- Has anyone else encountered a problem like this?

I would avoid posting such a potentially ignorant question on stackoveflow, but I'm very close to launch for a class project.

Comment: Two words: Show code.

Comment: https://github.com/jamessteininger/ProjectDoge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `<form class` tag on **line 91** of the application.html.erb should fix it.

Comment: You are a saint! Thank you. I feel embarrassed, but much relieved.